# robots.txt error : Content Type should be text/plain

Tags: text, seo, content-type, robots.txt

I'm testing my site with the software called `Search Engine Optimization (SEO) Toolkit 1.0` it displays this error :

> The content type for the response from "htpp://mysite.com/robots.txt"
>   is "text/html". The Web server should return "text/plain" as the
>   content type for a Robots.txt file.

My robots.txt file is simply this :

```
User-agent: * 
Allow: /
```

Saved with UTF-8 Without BOM Encoding.

Is this wrong?

What should be a default, harmless `robots.txt` file?

Thanks !

Comment: Unless you use mysite.com, that's why we have example.com for examples

Comment: I did not know it was off-topic before I asked this question. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a MIME type issue and needs to be configured in your server.

Here is a link: http://www.nextthing.org/archives/2007/03/12/robotstxt-adventure

For your specific hosting provider, they insert a small snippet of tracking javascript. Disable that feature following the customer service support in the comments and the mimetype should render.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using a free web host called 000webhost, so I guess I cannot change the server configuration. So there is nothing to do ?

Comment: Here: http://www.000webhost.com/forum/customer-assistance/31540-robots-txt-displays-html.html